# Export function from inside a React function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a function that handles React Native location. For demonstration:

```
const useLocation = () => {
  const [fetchingLocation, setFetchingLocation] = useState(true);
  ...

  const changeSystemPermissions = useCallback(() => {...});

  useEffect(() => {
    //does many things
  }, [...])
}
```

I need to have the function `changeSystemPermissions` inside useLocation as it uses the state.
I realize that I can export the `changeSystemPermissions` function as a const with a `return [changeSystemPermissions, ...]` and then import it in another component with:

```
const [
  changeSystemPermissions,
  ...
] = useLocation();
```

However, it will ALSO run the useEffect function. I do want it to run once, but I need to access `changeSystemPermissions` in several other components and I don't want the useEffect to run multiple times.

I was thinking I will just take out the `changeSystemPermissions` function outside of `useLocation`, but it needs to use the state. I suppose I COULD pass the state vars into the `changeSystemPermissions` when it is outside `useLocation`, but that would be verbose and ugly.

How can I export `changeSystemPermissions` and just that function without having to import the whole `useLocation` function?

Answer (score 2):

Can you move the useEffect to the component one ?

```js
const useLocation = () => {
  const [fetchingLocation, setFetchingLocation] = useState(true);
  
  const changeSystemPermissions = useCallback(() => {
     ...
  });

  const funcToExecute = useCallback(() => {
     ....
  }, []);

  return { changeSystemPermissions, funcToExecute } 
}
```

And put it in the component :

```js
const {
  changeSystemPermissions,
  funcToExecute, 
} = useLocation();


useEffect(() => {
    funcToExecute()
}, [...])
```

Also, if you really need the `useEffect` to be in the custom hook,

maybe you can add a param to this hook.

```js
const useLocation = (shouldTriggerEffect) => {
  const [fetchingLocation, setFetchingLocation] = useState(true);
  
  const changeSystemPermissions = useCallback(() => {
     ...
  });
  
  useEffect(() => {
     if (shouldTriggerEffect) {
         ...
     }
  }, [shouldTriggerEffect])

  return { changeSystemPermissions, funcToExecute } 
}
```

And then in the component,

```js
const {
  changeSystemPermissions,
} = useLocation(false);
```

Tell me if I misunderstood something or if it helps :)

Comment: I wrote that in my question. I can't do it because it will run useLocation, which includes several useEffects and I don't want these to run. When you do `... = useLocation()` it will run the function and everything inside it.

Comment: Oh ok, I updated my answer maybe you can move the useEffect to the component.

Comment: Or add a param to the hook. Let me know if it helps :)

Comment: I suppose your answer is correct, given that I simplified my setup. Indeed, it makes sense to separate the callback functions and the useEffect. However, in my case my useEffect functions and callbacks are many, they use state, and are all intermingled.

Answer (score 1):

When ever you call a hook inside a React functional component, it will create a new state for that hook and not sharing among components. But there is a library which could help you achieve that:

https://github.com/betula/use-between

You could follow example to use this library or maybe just read the code and utilize the approach for your case to share the hook state between components.